# jQuery .map() returning without undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I have an object array and I want to create a new array with the `id`s only. Some records have `id` and others don't.

So I have something like:

```
var myMap = arr.map(function(e) {
    return e.id;
});

console.log(myMap); // [undefined, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd like it to return just `[2, 3, 4]`, if possible.

This JSFiddle should explain a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/Lnmj0w8k/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible with just Array.map, you have to filter as well.

```
var myMap = arr.map(function(e) {
    return e.id;
}).filter(function(x) {
    return typeof x !== 'undefined';
});
```

As the ID's are always strings, you can do it like this as well

```
var myMap = arr.map(function(e) {
    return 'id' in e ? e.id : false;
}).filter(Boolean);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnmj0w8k/13/)

Comment: Thanks for the `Boolean` example.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myMap = arr.filter(function(e) {
        return e.hasOwnProperty("id")
    }).map(function(e) {
    return e.hasOwnProperty("id") ? e.id : null;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnmj0w8k/11/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you stick to pure jQuery your only option is to combine your `map` with a `filter`, or otherwise post-process the map results yourself.

However, if you combine jQuery with the popular Underscore.js library, the problem becomes trivial thanks to Underscore's compact method:

```
var myMap = arr.map(function(e) {
    return e.id;
});
myMap = _(myMap).compact();
```

But if you use Underscore, there's an even simpler way to do the same thing, because Underscore has a method specifically for extracting a certain property from an object:

```
var myMap = _(arr).pluck('id');
myMap = _(myMap).compact();
```

You can even chain the two together:

```
var myMap = _(arr).chain().pluck('id').compact().value();
```

or you can throw in the Underscore Grease library to get what I consider to be the simplest possible solution:

```
var myMap = _(arr).pluck_('id').compact();
```